# Exception in the insertion process SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, exception, insert

I have an exception which show in the insertion process into SQL Server. I am trying to send data from the local server in get method like this

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated
>   [image: schema of the table in sql server]
>   http://localhost:33191/json/deviceInfo.ashx?action=add_device&**googleID=APA91bEinvj-e2IuwqUFPB0c9RLd9DYp6ljMm_OTppzGCH_qBWG5g20pQ_A3XnYOvkBP7zEVVbiUYSWzWnHVzT0ZKaXm6qm9WahknqApALtqTNENd2eS3fOycfJcwE9sTpTLGI3ieOJP**&groupID=1234&userName=group1&password=123456&simNo=0522902313&simIP=0.0.0.0&group_name=ram1&macAddress=

```
//insert new group into database
SqlConnection conn = createConnection();
conn.Open();

string sql = "insert into [GROUP_DEVICES] (GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME, userName, password, simNo, simIP, macAddress, googleID, isActive) "
           + " VAlUES (@GROUP_ID, @GROUP_NAME, @userName, @password, @simNo, @simIP, @macAddress, @googleID, '0')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GROUP_ID", groupID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GROUP_NAME", GROUP_NAME);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@simNo", simNo);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@simIP", simIP);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@macAddress", macAddress);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@googleID", googleID);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: what is the exception? As per my understanding you are specifying '0' for BIT isActive in the database table.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be very clear, the data which you are trying to insert and the column length is not matching. You are probably trying to insert a larger value to a small column length.

**For example:** If you try to insert GROUP_NAME of 50 characters and the column you have defined as 20 characters in your table, then you will get the error which you are getting right now.

**Resolution:** You have to modify your column length to the appropriate length so that it can hold the data which you are trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when length of values you are inserting are larger than actual length of column you have specified for database table.

**String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.**

Please check all column lengths and values you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Schema of the table like this]

Schema of the table like this which show the length of googleID

Comment: 1. This should be added in  your question instead of an answer. 2. What are the other values which you are trying to insert? 3. Are you sure that the exception is coming from this line?

Comment: This link in accepted just i changed the google id   http://localhost:33191/json/deviceInfo.ashx?action=add_device&googleID=APA91bEinvjeLtqTNENd2eS3fOycfJcwE9s&groupID=1234&userName=group1&password=123456&simNo=0522902313&simIP=0.0.0.0&group_name=ram1&macAddress=